# Html2canvas for table is cutting image in only visible row ( without scroll )

Tags: angular, pdf-generation, html2canvas

I'm trying to download the table in pdf which is the bottom component of the page, but while taking screenshot it is only printing the rows which are visible without scrolling.

I'm not using the html2canvas for whole page only the table that is bottom of the page, even the download button is at the bottom of the page, where whole table is visible:

```
download()
{
    var data = document.getElementById('table'); //Id of the table

    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png,1.0') 
        var pdf = new jsPdf('l', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  

        var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();    
        var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

        let widthRatio = width / canvas.width;
        let heightRatio = height / canvas.height;

        let ratio = widthRatio > heightRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio

        pdf.addImage(imgData, "PNG", 0, 0, canvas.width * ratio, canvas.height * ratio,);
        pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
    });  
}
```